# Query with a group by and multiple "count"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a MySQL table with some unique codes grouped by a column called `tag`. Each code represents one line in the MySQL table and has an integer column called `used` (with a value of 0 or 1).

My aim is to have a query to list all tags along with the total number of codes, the number of used codes (`used` = 1) and the number of unused codes (`used` = 0) for this specific tag.

I am able to retrieve the list of tags from the "codes" table with the following query :

```
SELECT tag FROM codes WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY tag;
```

The end result would look like this :

- tag1 : 12 codes used and 14 codes unused for a total of 26 codes
- tag2 : 2 codes used and 6 codes unused for a total of 8 codes

But I'm wondering if I can achieve my goal in just one single query. Can you help on this point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation such as

```
SELECT tag, 
       SUM(used = 1) AS used_codes, 
       SUM(used = 0) AS unused_codes, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_codes 
  FROM codes 
 WHERE user_id = ? 
 GROUP BY tag;
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. used_codes, unused_codes and total_codes return all the same value : the total number of codes. It seems like the conditions are not taken in consideration

Comment: retry please @fraxool , just replaced COUNT with SUM aggregation

Comment: You can just use `sum(used)` and `sum(1-used)`.